# About an equation of exterior measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis

Suppose $E_1\subset E_2...\subset E_n…$
Prove $$m^*(\cup_{n=1}^{∞}E_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}m^*(E_n)$$
let E=$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty }E_n$

use the definition of $m^*(E)$ ,I have proof $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}m^*E_n\leq m^*(\cup_{n=1}^{∞}E_n）$$

Here is my proof

For any $\epsilon>0$,there exist an open set G, such that E$\subset G$,and $m^*G\leq m^*(E)+\epsilon $

For any n$\in N$ $$E_n\subset G$$

So $m^*(E_n)\leq m^*(G)$

That means $m^*(E_n)\leq m^*(E)+\epsilon$
Let $n\rightarrow \infty$and for $\epsilon $is arbitrary we get $$m^*(E_n)\leq m^*(E)$$

If I can proof $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}m^*E_n\ge m^*(E)$ then I finish the proof .But I failed

Definition :$m^*(A)=inf\{mG|G \text{ is an open set satisfy } A\subset G\}$

Comment: Is this Lebesgue outer measure on the line?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I edited my question .i think so